# Use external scss variables in angular-ionic project

Tags: css, angular, ionic5

So I'm working on an existing angular-ionic application, using : angular 12 and ionic 5.
I need to use an external library used exclusively to generate styles, imported in the node_modules.

There is only one file to import which contains all the elements needed in the application, with a bit of the code included  as follow :

**custom-css-library/dist/lib.css**

```
.theme-one,
:root {
  --bg-primary: 0, 40, 87;
  --bg-secondary: 115, 154, 188;
  --success: 34, 197, 94;
  --error: 239, 68, 68;
}
.theme-two{
  --bg-primary: 207, 16, 45;
  --bg-secondary: 204, 204, 204;
  --success: 34, 197, 94;
  --error: 239, 68, 68;
}

.btn--primary {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(var(--bg-primary), var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  border-color: rgba(var(--bg-primary), var(--tw-border-opacity));
  color: rgba(var(--primary-contrast), var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
```

I have imported this file in the **global.scss** file :

```
/* External CSS*/
@import 'custom-css-library/dist/lib.css';
```

And then used the main class on my  tag in the **index.html**

```
<bodyclass="theme-one">
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

All seems to work as intended when I use the basic classes. My troubles start when I try to directly reference the variables.

For instance, when needing to display en error message, I tried this in the page :

**page.html**

```
<div>
  <p class="custom-error">Some custom error</p>
</div>
```

**page.scss**

```
.custom-error {
  color: var(--error);
}
```

The color is not taken into account, and the developer console displays on error on the "style" tab :
*--error is not defined*

What am I missing to correctly declare/import the file in order to load the variables in my scss files?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure the `angular.json` file like this.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "your-project": {
      "projectType": "application",
....
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            .....
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/..../yourstuff.css"
              },
....
```

Also, it would be great if you can provide *stackblitz* link or *codesandbox*. We can see your problem easier and can solve it more quickly.

Comment: I thought abut a codesanddbox, but since it's a component inside a component inside a page and all of this is propriatary work, I can't easily rework all of this in a way that works and would still present the bug :(